# Filtro para uma matriz multidimensional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Como eu poderia fazer para trazer tudo na view e filtrar em um combobox pela opção da turma?

```
$scope.dadosUserAndTurma = [
                  {
                    idUser:20,
                    nome: "Carlos",
                        turmas: [
                             {turma: "Turma 1", value: 1},
                                 {turma: "Turma 2", value: 2},
                                 {turma: "Turma 3", value: 3}
                               ]
                  },
                  {
                    idUser:21,
                    nome: "Luiz",
                        turmas: [
                             {turma: "Turma 1", value: 1},
                                 {turma: "Turma 3", value: 3}
                               ]
                  },
                  {
                    idUser:22,
                    nome: "Priscilla",
                        turmas: [
                             {turma: "Turma 2", value: 1}
                               ]
                  } ,
                 {
                    idUser:24,
                    nome: "Pedro",
                        turmas: []
                  }
              ];

}
```

Exemplo no
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4scj9g2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é criar uma função para cuidar desse filtro. Eu atualizei teu [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4scj9g2/3/) com uma possível solução. Em resumo, eu ajustei a sua função `filterTurma()` dessa forma:

```
$scope.filterTurma = function(usuario) {

    // Caso o valor seja '!!' (valor que você está atribuindo para "Todos"),
    // apenas retornar 'true' para todos os casos continuarem aparecendo...
    if ($scope.search_turmas.turmas.value == '!!')
        return true;

    // Do contrário, iterar as turmas do usuário, e verificar se ao menos
    // uma delas corresponde com a turma selecionada no combobox...
    for (var i = 0; i < usuario.turmas.length; i++) {
        var turma = usuario.turmas[i];
        if (turma.value == $scope.search_turmas.turmas.value)
            return true;
    }

    // caso nenhuma tenha correspondido, retornar 'false' para ocultar esse usuário...
    return false;
};
```

Resumindo o código, no seu combo você tem as turmas, e ainda uma opção **"Todos"** com o valor **'!!'**. No filtro, apenas verificamos se o valor atual do item selecionado no `combobox` é esse, do contrário, verificamos se ao menos uma turma corresponde à turma selecionada. No seu HTML, para aplicar esse filtro, basta fazer assim:

```
<tr ng-repeat="usuario in dadosUserAndTurma | filter:{nome:search_nome} | filter:filterTurma">
```

Note que eu não utilizamos **parêntesis** no nome do método (o *angularjs* vai automaticamente passar o usuário atual na iteração para o método), além disso eu mantive o filtro original pelo nome, ou seja, ambos filtros se complementam (e você pode combinar quantos filtros quiser).

---

> No seu JSFiddle original, o objeto `dadosUserAndTurma` tinha uma usuária **Priscila** contendo a turma 2 com o `value` 1. No meu fiddle atualizado eu mudei esse valor para 2, pois parecia ser o correto, talvez você precise ajustar isso também no seu código original.